# A PL/PgSQL Trigger to return only the updated fields

Tags: ruby, database, postgresql

I am using, ruby and pg gem to connect to my PG Database. I am struck with triggers. I need to return only the updated values from the trigger function.

```
require 'pg'

TRIGGER_FUNCTION = %{
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notify_account()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
    BEGIN
      NOTIFY accounts_trigger;
      IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
        // Here is where I need to return, the changed fields alone
      ELSE
        RETURN NEW;
      END IF;
    END
$$
}

DROP_TRIGGER = %{
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS accounts_notify_trigger ON accounts
}


TRIGGER = %{
CREATE TRIGGER accounts_notify_trigger
AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT OR DELETE
ON accounts
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE notify_account();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you mean by "return" just the changed fields. That's what the `NEW` tuple does - you *can't* omit the unchanged fields, since then you'd be returning a tuple that wasn't compatible with the table row and the trigger would fail.

So I'm going to guess you mean that you want to *log* the changed items only.

SQL isn't great at comparing tuples as key/value sets. What I'd tend to do in this situation is turn each tuple into a key/value set via `hstore` then use set operations to extract only the different pairs.

Handily, `hstore` provides an operator that does just what we want, so we don't even have to mess around with turning the hstore into an SQL key/value list and using SQL set operations.

Try something like:

```
RAISE NOTICE 'Changed fields: %', (hstore(NEW) - hstore(OLD));
```

You'll need to `CREATE EXTENSION hstore;` as superuser if you haven't already.

If you're attempting to write an audit trigger you might want to check out http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus .